# What is the name of the effect for showing past days in movies?

Tags: film-techniques, star-wars, rogue-one

In *[Rogue One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/)*, Jyn Erso remembers her childhood days.

Her childhood/past days were shown with some effects like characters talking with a low voice with echo, with high background music, slow motion (not very slow) and shaky camera.

What is the name of this effect for showing past days in movies?

Answer (score 4):

Showing some past event is called a [Flashback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_(narrative)).

> In movies and television, several camera techniques and special effects have evolved to alert the viewer that the action shown is a flashback or flashforward; for example, the edges of the picture may be deliberately blurred, photography may be jarring or choppy, or unusual coloration or sepia tone, or monochrome when most of the story is in full color, may be used.

Comment: I know There is wiki article on Flashback, But What is the specific name of it? In wiki article there is no mention of shaky camera & low voice. I will wait for better answer to approve it.

Comment: I believe there is only one name for such technique. Flashback. Shaky cam, and low voice, have their own names, and at best you'd say the Flashback was presented with shaky cam and voice modulation. I very much doubt there is a distinct name for a specific way to present flashback.

Comment: This vehicle is as old as storytelling.  I doubt there's any other name for it.

Comment: There IS a name for it, I just can't remember it. I agree with you user48432.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to CyberClaw's answer:

I also think the effect is called [Flashback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_(narrative)), I belive the camera is shaking and the voices are in a low volume because she is **remembering** something, and usually our memories are not very clear. And it is very difficult for us to remember all the details of a memory.

In case you want more details, each one is a separate effect:

- [Flashback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_(narrative))
- [Shaky Camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaky_camera)
- [Slow Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_motion).